# Option type overhead for primitive types

Tags: scala, option-type, template-specialization, boxing

Does the Scala `Option` type incur an overhead of two objects per primitive type value? In other words, is the `Option` type specialized for primitives, or does it always double-box them (I'm counting `Some(...)` as a box)?

Comment: Yes. JVM has small object optimization so you don't need to worry about that

Comment: It will double box since `Option` is not specialized. Now, unless you perform serious benchmarking to be sure that would be a problem for your use case I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @SwiftMango do you have a link for reference?